# MKMapView without full screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

I would like to create a pop-up style map in 275x380 size. I created the view in the interface builder, the view, and the map view has the same size, 275x380. Although, when i logged the frame of the view in viewWillAppear, i get 320x460. Any suggestions how should i fix this?

Comment: ou can reset frame of view. Also in interface builder, how are you creating view.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/g/717/screenshot20130103at123.png/
Here is the settings that i used in IB.

Comment: you are creating view in wrong way. just create an empty nib and select view from library. In this way you can set view of your desired size else you will get 320x460 size.

Comment: Okay, i'll give it a try :)